# Android: Java Error Unexpected token (Array)

Tags: java, android, arrays, android-studio

I am facing an error which isn't in fact an error. I am using Android Studio and want to create an Array but it tells me that there are unexpected token..

[image]

As you can see in the image I wanted to make a String Array, but things are not going as supposed to. Is this an error with Android Studio?

Comment: Move the assignment inside onCreate() or another method.

Comment: Wow this worked thanks, but can you explain why? Why doesn't it work within a class?

Comment: @MichaelJancen-Widmer Because code belongs in methods. The previous line actually declares and initializes a *field*, not a variable. The second line is an assignment *statement*, and must be in a code block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move it to `onCreate()` and try again.

Or you may use as below

[image: new way]

Comment: This worked for me but can you please explain why the class isn't enough?

Comment: @MichaelJancen-Widmer There's an other way.. See the updated answer. Thank you,.

Comment: @MichaelJancen-Widmer see Andreas' comment for more info

Comment: This is great thanks a lot, haven't found anything on the web :)

Comment: @MichaelJancen-Widmer You are welcome.. Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 0):

move the code to onCreate method

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_numbers);
        String[] words = new String[10];
         words[1]= "hello";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your declaring that code outside the onCreate() method thats why it is throwing that error.

declare your array inside onCreate() method

Answer (score 0):

you can also use like this

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {
        String[] words = new String[10];


        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
              words[1]= "hello";

        }
}
```